# WordPress - Sync wordpress post with JSON feed

Tags: rss, feed, json, sync

I hope you all are doing well.

I need to ask something, I tried searching for this but unable to get any relevant answer. I have a JSON feed and using that feed I want to create posts and want to sync/updated those posts whenever JSON feeds changes. Please guide me in this regards.

I know how to create post with JSON feed but don't know how to keep posts sync with that JSON feed.

What I want to achieve using that feed is: 
a. If post doesn't exists in Wordpress DB then add it 
b. If post exists in Wordpress DB then update it

**Updated**

One more question I need to ask, what if JSON changes and the item in wordpress post is not available in that updated JSON, in simple words I also want to delete all the items available in posts that previously available in JSON but after JSON changes it's not there.

Thanks, 
Neil Bannet

Comment: [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) does exactly that: if the passed post ID exists, the post is updated; otherwise a post is created. What problems exactly do you have to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The important step is to assign a unique ID to every item you get from the source. Hopefully the JSON feed already includes one, but otherwise you will have to somehow create one yourself based on the JSON content.

Once you have the value, you store it as a meta value of the post being created. The code should look something like this

```
$json = get_json_item();
$uuid = get_json_uuid($json);
// check if exist based on the json_uuid meta
$t = get_posts(array('meta_key' => 'json_uuid', 'meta_value' => $uuid));
if (count($t) == 0) { // create new post
  $pid = wp_insert_post(values extracted from $json);
  update_post_meta($pid,'json_uuid',$uuid);
} else { // post exist
  wp_insert_post(array('ID' => $p[0]->ID,values extracted from $json));
}
```